# how to print a sorted list which contains a tuple formed by a tuple and a value int

Tags: python, list, sorting, printing, tuples

I have this list, I wanna sorted my tuples based on the int value

```
list = [((u'Wyndham', u'Grand'), 1), ((u'Pittsburgh', u'My'), 1), ((u'Poor', u'Terrible'), 1), ((u'PLACE', u'IN'), 1), ((u'Poor', u'Everything'), 1), ((u'Junior', u'Suite'), 1), ((u'WE', u'HAD'), 1), ((u'Wyndham', u'People'), 1), ((u'United', u'States'), 1), ((u'NIGHTMARE\U0001f623\U0001f623\U0001f623', u'Dirty'), 1), ((u'A', u'FAKE'), 1), ((u'SEPERATE', u'TIMES'), 1), ((u'DO', u'NOT'), 1), ((u'WORST', u'PLACE'), 1), ((u'Burger', u'King'), 1), ((u'FINAL', u'AFTER'), 1), ((u'STAY', u'THERE'), 1), ((u'Hotel', u'California'), 1), ((u'Don', u'\u2019'), 4), ((u'THERE', u'Nothing'), 1), ((u'HOTEL', u'CALIFORNIA'), 1), ((u'Santa', u'Monica'), 4), ((u'Universal', u'Studios'), 1)]
```

I have tried this:

```
sorted ( list, key=lambda x: x[ 1 ], reverse=True )
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sorted(list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True )
```

Output:

```
[(('Don', '’'), 4), (('Santa', 'Monica'), 4), (('Wyndham', 'Grand'), 1), (('Pittsburgh', 'My'), 1), (('Poor', 'Terrible'), 1), (('PLACE', 'IN'), 1), (('Poor', 'Everything'), 1), (('Junior', 'Suite'), 1), (('WE', 'HAD'), 1), (('Wyndham', 'People'), 1), (('United', 'States'), 1), (('NIGHTMARE', 'Dirty'), 1), (('A', 'FAKE'), 1), (('SEPERATE', 'TIMES'), 1), (('DO', 'NOT'), 1), (('WORST', 'PLACE'), 1), (('Burger', 'King'), 1), (('FINAL', 'AFTER'), 1), (('STAY', 'THERE'), 1), (('Hotel', 'California'), 1), (('THERE', 'Nothing'), 1), (('HOTEL', 'CALIFORNIA'), 1), (('Universal', 'Studios'), 1)]
```

Comment: Is this not *exactly* OP' s current approach?